# scraping iframe data table inserted using javascript

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Trying to scrape a site where the data table is in an iframe that is dynamically loaded. The url never changes and i have used selenium to navigate to the table. But once there, it still does not find the iframe which has the id of "theiframe". I see the iframe using inspect element, but when i used my script it does not find it.

I have tried scraping by targeting the iframe via xpath `(("//iframe[@id='theiframe']")` and by css selector `("theiframe")`. Still get a message saying it **can't find the element**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

myURL = "http://www.1line.williams.com/Transco/index.html"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(myURL)
time.sleep(3)

action = ActionChains(driver)
step1 = 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[4]/ul[1]/li[5]/a[1]')
action.move_to_element(step1).perform()
print("got to notice...waiting for menu")
time.sleep(1)
step2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[4]/ul[1]/li[5]/ul[1]/li[1]/a[1]")
action.move_to_element(step2).perform()
step2.click()

time.sleep(4)

# page_source = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='theiframe']")

page_source = driver.find_element_by_id("theiframe")
print(page_source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nested `iframe` present on the page.You need to switch to both the `iframes`.

**Frame 1** : ID='interiorFrame'

**Frame 2** : ID='theiframe'

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()` for two frames.

Try below code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.1line.williams.com/Transco/index.html")
action = ActionChains(driver)
step1=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[4]/ul[1]/li[5]/a[1]")))
action.move_to_element(step1).perform()
step2=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[4]/ul[1]/li[5]/ul[1]/li[1]/a[1]")))
action.move_to_element(step2).click(step2).perform()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,'interiorFrame')))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,'theiframe')))
page_source=driver.page_source
print(page_source)
```

Comment: KunduK, that came close, but in the html, it just says "loading":

 <b><font size="+1">
 Critical Notices<br>
 Loading...
 </font></b>

Comment: @SMJune : The website Not allowing frequent access to the page by bot.wait for some time or change browser to chrome.it will work.

Comment: Great!!! If it resolved your problem please accept this answer.Thanks!!!

Comment: thanks...was just checking if i can find the download links within and yes, i found them. Thanks!!!